# Overcoming gravity with fluid pressure

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, liquid

How would I determine if an upward flow of liquid at 100 bar forces a bed of porous solid upwards or flows through without affecting the same bed of material? Is it related to bulk density and pores?

Comment: This may be relevant : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/19841/10902

Comment: That's my other question unfortunately...

Comment: a solid object with known cross section experiences drag D = C_drag*rho*V*V*A/2; now introduce another coefficient, C_porous.  Determine it experimentally, and write a master's thesis on determining C_porous as a function of V. Then relate V to pressure differentials (design of thermofluid systems) and you're good to go